# Is it possible to use an anonymous object in Controller-Method?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, anonymous-types

is it possible to use an anonymous object in a Controller Method?

e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(/*Anonymous object here*/){
/*Do something here */
}

function GetSomething(settings, inputData) {
$.ajax({
    url: settings.url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: inputData,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#' + settings.target + '').html(data);
    }
});
```

}

Now I'd like to build a for example User-Object inside the Ajax-function

```
inputdata.Firstname: 'Max',
inputdata.Lastname: 'Mustermann',
inputdata.Age: 25
```

After that I'd like to use the "User-object" inside my Controller Method

```
public Actionresult Test(/*object*/ user){
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Firstname.ToString()){
    /*Do something*/
    }
}
```

Comment: No, C# doesn't do this sort of structural typing yet. You have to extract it to a class and accept an instance of that class as the argument.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Okay, I thought so. What do you mean by "extract to class?" pushing the variables as "standalone" variables (string name, string firstname, int age) and putting them together to an object inside the Method?

Comment: The first step in the model binding process is that internally in calls `Activator.CreateInstance()`, which can't be done on an anonymous object

Comment: So there is no other way than pushing every single variable itself to the Controller?

Comment: You either need a model with those 3 properties, or you need 3 parameters in the POST method (`string Firstname, string Lastname, int Age)` or just access the values yourself from `Request.Form`

Comment: @StephenMuecke And how would I be able to create an instance of that Model (C# class) inside my ajax/js function?

Comment: You cant in the ajax function - javascript is client side code and has no concept of a C# class. All you can do is create a javascript object as you have already done. If you want to bind to an object on postback, you need to create a model in your app that contains those 3 properties.